# (VBS) Make a list of multiple selection entries

Tags: list, vbscript, ms-word, ms-office

I have a text in Word and I select some words from it using Ctrl+Click, then after the paragraph I make a numerated list of those selected words. It looks like this

[image: Text]

I was wondering if it was possible to use VBS to create a macros, which would put a number after selected words and make a list of them afterwards. So far I have only managed to do something like this:

```
Sub MakeAList()

With Selection
   .Copy
   .MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
   .TypeParagraph
   .Paste
End With
End Sub
```

It copies the selected words and makes each one a paragraph right after the main one. I still make a list and put (*) after the word in the original text.

To clear up any confusion, the language is Chinese, and the words are not separated by spaces, but I'll try to use the "Split". What's important is when I select several words, let's say for 2-character words, the programm shows that I have selected 8 words (4*2), but **4 lines**, even if those words are in the same line. So I think I shouls experiment with the line counter, if there is any.

Comment: Could you please use latin letters?

Comment: I don't know your language, if it uses spaces to separate words or not. See the `split` command and something - `A = Split(Selection.Text, " "):For Each wrd In A:MsgBox wrd:Next`